# SQL data type for multiple decimal places

Tags: sql-server-2012

What data type in SQL Server will insert the correct number of decimal places for the number entered into a table. When I try to enter a number like so 6.828.678 into a deciaml or numeric field it says input value was not in the correct format. What data type do i use so that it allows this?

Comment: Is that item of data used in a numerical fashion, e.g. do you need to sum, calculate average etc. on that? Otherwise, I'd just store it as a string

Comment: Are those supposed to be decimal places or thousands separators?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to store the data in format `6.828.678` (as in your post) then consider using `VARCHAR` data type.

You can't store `6.828.678` format data into either `deciaml` or `numeric` type field cause they are not valid number format and that's why you are getting the error.

Not sure, but per your comment if you want to `SUM` and compare the value then store it as `INT` datatype but before inserting the data make sure to remove the `.`.

You can use `REPLACE()` function like `CAST(REPLACE('6.828.678','.','') as INT)`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Although the OP hasn't specified this yet, maybe the decimal is a thousands separator.

Comment: Yes May be but even in that case, it has to be stored as string literal I believe. Or, remove the `.` and then store it as `INT`

Comment: I need to be able to perform sums and compare the value in the column also. So a VARCHAR would not suit would it?

Comment: @user2437588, in that case you will have to store as `INT` type. Check edited answer if that makes sense.

Comment: @user2437588: I still don't know what `6.828.678` represents.  Is it three different integers?  Is it one integer with a decimal place as a "thousands separator?  Something else?

Comment: Its supposed to be thousand sepeartors, sorry

Comment: @user2437588: Please give a manual example how you would sum two values